# How to iterate through a JSONObject (Java json-simple)

Tags: java, json

I am using [`json-simple`](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/). If I have a JSON like:

```
[
    {"id":"1","name":"...","description":"...","dtStart":"2012-03-27 03:00:00","dtEnd":"2012-03-28 03:00:00","activities":""},
    {"id":"1","name":"...","description":"...","dtStart":"2012-03-27 03:00:00","dtEnd":"2012-03-28 03:00:00","activities":""},{"id":"1","name":"...","description":"...","dtStart":"2012-03-27 03:00:00","dtEnd":"2012-03-28 03:00:00","activities":""},
    {"id":"1","name":"...","description":"...","dtStart":"2012-03-27 03:00:00","dtEnd":"2012-03-28 03:00:00","activities":""}
]
```

How can I iterate through it?

Comment: There is a [bunch of examples in the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples). What exactly have you tried and have problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that you have shown is of a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html), as it is enclosed between `[` and `]`.
You should be able to iterate through it like any other java `Array`.

Comment: I don't know how and why OP accepted this answer. The OP was talking about `JSONArray` in `json-simple` library. While this answer points to another library provided by json.org. Both JSONArrays are different. `json-simple`'s `JSONArray` is actually a subclass of `ArrayList`. You *cannot* iterate it like a primitive array.

Answer (score 0):

That will create a List of 3 Maps.

```
for (Object o : (List)parser.parse(json)){
    Map m = (Map)o;
    //handle map
}
```